# d3.js realtime line chart with circle

Tags: javascript, d3.js, linechart

I'm trying to make a d3 realtime line chart with circle at the data point.
However, circles are gathered on the left side and it is not given to the data point.

This method is fine for static data to show circles with line chart.

```
    chart.append('circle')
        .data(data)
        .attr('class', 'ciecle')
        .attr("cy", line.x())
        .attr("cy", line.y())
        .attr("r", 5)
        .attr("fill", 'blue');
```

However, it does not work with dynamically increasing data.
I want to move the circles with realtime line chat.

The follow code was forked from this URL
http://bl.ocks.org/KevinGutowski/131809cc7bcd1d37e10ca37b89da9630

Would you please let me how to change the code?

```
    <svg id="chart"></svg>
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var data = [];
        var width = 500;
        var height = 500;
        var globalX = 0;
        var duration = 100;
        var max = 500;
        var step = 10;
        var chart = d3.select('#chart')
        .attr('width', width + 50)
        .attr('height', height + 50);
        var x = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 500]).range([0, 500]);
        var y = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0, 500]).range([500, 0]);
        // -----------------------------------
        var line = d3.line()
                            .x(function(d){ return x(d.x); })
                            .y(function(d){ return y(d.y); });
        var smoothLine = d3.line().curve(d3.curveCardinal)
                            .x(function(d){ return x(d.x); })
                            .y(function(d){ return y(d.y); });
        // -----------------------------------
        // Draw the axis
        var xAxis = d3.axisBottom().scale(x);
        var axisX = chart.append('g').attr('class', 'x axis')
                     .attr('transform', 'translate(0, 500)')
                     .call(xAxis);

        var path = chart.append('path');
        var circle = chart.append('circle');

        // Main loop
        function tick() {
            // Generate new data
            var point = {
                x: globalX,
                y: ((Math.random() * 450 + 50) >> 0)
            };
            data.push(point);
            globalX += step;
            // Draw new line
            path.datum(data)
                .attr('class', 'smoothline')
                .attr('d', smoothLine);
// Append circles. 　It should given to data point
            chart.append('circle')
                .data(data)
                .attr('class', 'ciecle')
                .attr("cy", line.x())
                .attr("cy", line.y())
                .attr("r", 5)
                .attr("fill", 'blue');

            // Shift the chart left
            x.domain([globalX - (max - step), globalX]);
            axisX.transition()
                 .duration(duration)
                 .ease(d3.easeLinear,.1)
                 .call(xAxis);
            path.attr('transform', null)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear,.1)
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(globalX - max) + ')');
 //move with line           
circle.attr('transform', null)
                .transition()
                .duration(duration)
                .ease(d3.easeLinear,.1)
                .attr('transform', 'translate(' + x(globalX - max) + ')')
                .on('end', tick);
            // Remote old data (max 50 points)
            if (data.length > 50) data.shift();
        }
        tick();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The coordinates of the path get repeatedly updated in the `tick` function (which repeatedly calls itself) using `path.datum(data)`. You also need to update the locations of the circles on each tick using the adjusted (shifted) scale, which gets changed here:

```
x.domain([globalX - (max - step), globalX]);
```

To make the transitions smooth, you also need to update the transforms in each tick. You could update it for each circle and the path itself individually, but I just put both in a group (`<g>`) element and animate the whole group. Here's a working example:

http://bl.ocks.org/Sohalt/9715be30ba57e00f2275d49247fa7118/43a24a4dfa44738a58788d05230407294ab7a348